# Longest common sequence between many sub-sequences

Tags: python, dictionary, sequence

Fancy title :) 
I have a file that contains the following:

```
>sequence_40
ABCDABDCABCDBACDBACDBACDBACDABDCDC
ACDCCDCABDCADCADBCACBDCABD
>sequence_41
DCBACDBACDADCDCDCABCDCACBDCBDACBDC
BCDBABABBABACDCDBCACDBACDBACDBACDC
BCDB
...
```

Then, I have a function that returns a dictionary (called dict) that returns the sequences as keys and the strings (combined on one line) as values for the keys. The sequences range from 40 to 59.
I want to take a dictionary of sequences and return the longest common sub-sequence found in ALL the sequences. Managed to find some help here on stackoverflow and made a code that only compares the LAST TWO strings in that dictionary, not all of them :). 
This is the code

```
def longest_common_sequence(s1, s2):
    m = [[0] * (1 + len(s2)) for i in range(1 + len(s1))]
    longest, x_longest = 0, 0
    for x in range(1, 1 + len(s1)):
        for y in range(1, 1 + len(s2)):
            if s1[x - 1] == s2[y - 1]:
                m[x][y] = m[x - 1][y - 1] + 1
                if m[x][y] > longest:
                    longest = m[x][y]
                    x_longest = x
            else:
                m[x][y] = 0
    return s1[x_longest - longest: x_longest]

for i in range(40,59):
    s1=str(dictionar['sequence_'+str(i)])
    s2=str(dictionar['sequence_'+str(i+1)])
longest_common_sequence(s1,s2)
```

How can I modify it to get the common subsequence among ALL sequences in dictionary? Thanks!

Comment: Start by not using `dict` as a variable name; it masks the `dict` type/constructor, and will bite you in no time at all.

Comment: Changed it right now :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: As @lmcarreiro pointed out, there is a relevant difference between *substrings* (or *subarrays* or *sublists*) and *subsequences*.  To my understanding we are all talking about *substrings* here, so I will use this term in my answer.

Guillaumes answer can be improved:

```
def eachPossibleSubstring(string):
  for size in range(len(string) + 1, 0, -1):
    for start in range(len(string) - size + 1):
      yield string[start:start+size]

def findLongestCommonSubstring(strings):
  shortestString = min(strings, key=len)
  for substring in eachPossibleSubstring(shortestString):
    if all(substring in string
        for string in strings if string != shortestString):
      return substring

print findLongestCommonSubstring([
  'ABCDABDCABCDBACDBACDBACDBACDABDCDCACDCCDCABDCADCADBCACBDCABD',
  'DCBACDBACDADCDCDCABCDCACBDCBDACBDCBCDBABABBABACDCDBCACDBACDBACDBACDCBCDB',
])
```

This prints:

```
ACDBACDBACDBACD
```

This is faster because I return the first found and search from longest to shortest.

The basic idea is this:  Take each possible substring of the shortest of your strings (in the order from the longest to the shortest) and see if this substring can be found in all other strings.  If so, return it, otherwise try the next substring.

You need to understand *generators*.  Try e. g. this:

```
for substring in eachPossibleSubstring('abcd'):
  print substring
```

or

```
print list(eachPossibleSubstring('abcd'))
```

Comment: Hah! This will take me a while to understand :D

Comment: Btw, I have the feeling that this problem can have faster solutions, similar to the [Boyer-Moore-Horspool algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore%E2%80%93Horspool_algorithm).

Comment: Is this a solution for sub-string or sub-sequence? By the example, looks like you are working with sub-strings, not sub-sequences...

Comment: A string is a sequence of characters.  From the algorithm perspective there is no difference.  Could you explain more what you mean?

Comment: From wikipedia: "unlike substrings, subsequences are not required to occupy consecutive positions within the original sequences"

Comment: Interesting aspect, thanks for pointing that out!  I think we all (asker & answerers) were talking about substrings here (from index a to index b).  The implementation in the Q here also makes clear that this is meant, also because the GATC-letters indicate gene-stuff where substrings are interesting, not subsequences in the meaning of the WP article.  It might be a good idea to change The Q and all As here accordingly, i. e. to change all "subsequences" to "substrings".

Comment: Btw, I think not many programmers are aware of the different meaning of the term "subsequence" in mathematics (so I think that's a domain-related issue) and use it instead for what is called a *slice* in Python, i. e. a part of the original from index a to b, i. e. consecutive elements.  *S(ubs)equence* vs. *S(ubs)tring* are used to differentiate between lists of characters vs. list of more complex (less atomar) things only.

Comment: Hmm, reading more about applications, I see that also *subsequences* are relevant in genetics.  But from the way PO put things here I still think they were looking for substrings instead.

Comment: Yes, this question really was about substrings... I just pointed that out because I was looking for a good solution for Longest Common Subsequence (in the way that it is defined in WP)

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by defining a function to return all possible subsequences of a given sequence:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
def subsequences(sequence):
    "returns all possible subquences of a given sequence"
    for start, stop in combinations_with_replacement(range(len(sequence)), 2):
        if start < stop:
            yield sequence[start:stop]
```

then I'd make another method to check if a given subsequence in present in all given sequences:

```
def is_common_subsequence(sub, sequences):
    "returns True if <sub> is a common subsequence in all <sequences>"
    return all(sub in sequence for sequence in sequences)
```

then using the 2 methods above it is pretty easy to get all common subsequences in a given set of sequences:

```
def common_sequences(sequences):
    "return all subsequences common in sequences"
    shortest_seq = min(sequences, key=len)
    return set(subsequence for subsequence in subsequences(shortest_seq) \
       if is_common_subsequence(subsequence, sequences))
```

... and extracting the longuest sequence:

```
def longuest_common_subsequence(sequences):
    "returns the longuest subsequence in sequences"
    return max(common_sequences(sequences), key=len)
```

Result:

```
sequences = {
    41: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
    42: '123ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW',
    43: '123456ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST'
}

sequences2 = {
    0: 'ABCDEFGHIJ',
    1: 'DHSABCDFKDDSA',
    2: 'SGABCEIDEFJRNF'
}

print(longuest_common_subsequence(sequences.values()))
>>> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST

print(longuest_common_subsequence(sequences2.values()))
>>> ABC
```

Comment: Neat.  But you could optimize for checking from longest to shortest possible sequence and returning the first found instead of collecting all and then return the max.

Comment: Hey! This is what I was looking for. It's quite nice with all the functions inside. Can you please tell me what is this guy here : combinations_with_replacement ?

Comment: Oops, it's an import that I forgot to copy/paste. Fixed

Comment: @Alfe: taking only subsequences of the shortest input sequence is indeed a good idea. I'll update my answer

Comment: Demonstration was the main objective here, not optimisation ;)

Comment: This looks like sub-string too, not sub-sequence

Comment: @lmcarreiro A string and a list both being sequences, I don't understand that comment.

Comment: From wikipedia: "unlike substrings, subsequences are not required to occupy consecutive positions within the original sequences"

Comment: See my comments above at my answer.  I think the term "subsequence" here throughout this post is a misnomer.  It should have been "substrings" all the way.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a possible approach. First let's define a function that returns the longest substring between two strings:

```
def longest_substring(s1, s2):
    t = [[0]*(1+len(s2)) for i in range(1+len(s1))]
    l, xl = 0, 0
    for x in range(1,1+len(s1)):
        for y in range(1,1+len(s2)):
            if s1[x-1] == s2[y-1]:
                t[x][y] = t[x-1][y-1] + 1
                if t[x][y]>l:
                    l = t[x][y]
                    xl  = x
            else:
                t[x][y] = 0
    return s1[xl-l: xl]
```

Now I'll create a random `dict` of sequences for the example:

```
import random
import string

d = {i : ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(50)) for i in range(10)}

print d

{0: 'ASCUCEVJNIGWVMWMBBQQBZYBBNGQAJRYXACGFEIFWHMBCNYRGL', 1: 'HKUKZOJJUCRTSBLNZXCIBARLPNAPAABRBZEVGVILJAFCGWGQVV', 2: 'MMHCYPKECRJFEWTGYITMHZSNHAFEZVFYDAVILRYRKIDDBEFRVX', 3: 'DGBULRFJINFZEELDASRFBIRSADWMRAYMGCDAOJDKQIMXIRLTEI', 4: 'VDUFWZSXLRGOIMAHOAMZAIWDPTHDVDXUACRBASJMCUHREDORRH', 5: 'RFGAVHOWNKRZMYMSFSSNUGCKEWUNVETCDWJXSPBJHKSTPFNSJO', 6: 'HFMLMHCFSOEXBXWFAROIRGJNPRTKRWCEPLFOKGMXNUPCPWREWX', 7: 'CNPGSHGVIRLDXAADXUVWCTJCXUHQLALBUOJMXQBKXWHKGSJHEH', 8: 'UWDXXTRCFNCBUBEYGYTDWTPLNTRHYQWKTHPRVCBAWIMNGHULDC', 9: 'OOCJRXBZKJIGHZEJOOIKWKMQKIEQVPEDTFPJQAUQKJQVLOMGJB'}
```

Finally, we need to find the longest subsequence between all sequences:

```
import itertools
max([longest_substring(i,j) for i,j in itertools.combinations(d.values(), 2)], key=len)
```

Output:

```
'VIL'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The one thing I don't seem to understand is that your code's output 'VIL' does show in keys 1 and 2, but not in the rest :). I was interested in a sub-string, not separate letters. 
Example:
0: ABCDEFGHIJ
1: DHSABCDFKDDSA
2: SGABCEIDEFJRNF

The output should be 'ABC' as it is the longest common string in all of the above sequences.